# Get local BLOB from UUID using JS

Tags: blob, uuid, dropzone.js

I'm implementing file attachment for a chat app and use Dropzone.js for the purpose. It returns a file object that can later be transformed using transformFile method on the lib.

Whenever I'm attaching an image file, I get its content in a dataURL property as base64 string and everything works fine.
However, when I attach f.e. a PDF file, I get its UUID only.

Does anybody know if and how can I get the PDF BLOB using this UUID?

So far I'm trying to do it like this:

```
fetch(dzFile.upload.uuid)
  .then(r => r.blob())
  .then(blobFile => new File([blobFile], dzFile.name, { type: dzFile.type }))
  .then(file => {

  });
```

with the following result:

```
lastModified: 1591340121004
lastModifiedDate: Fri Jun 05 2020 09:55:21 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time) {}
name: "dummy.pdf"
size: 2129
type: "application/pdf"
webkitRelativePath: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems like this is easily solved by just calling dzFile[.arrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer).